# rearrange random string to consonant vowel consonant vowel order in python

Tags: python, string, algorithm, sorting

Having a random string such as `asftiopeiopv`, how to rearrange it in a word-alike following the pattern consonant-vowel-consonant-vowel-consonant?

In this case, it would for example become something like `safitopepivo`.

And where numbers also can be included which have the same level as vowels. For example having the random string `asft1op41opv` it would become `saf1top4p1vo`.

Comment: What is supposed to happen if there are more consonants than vowels or vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a more efficient way, but this should output the expected result:

```
string = "asft1op41opv"
convertedString = ""

p = re.compile('[aeiou0-9]')
vowelsAndNumbers = p.findall(string)
string = p.sub("",string)

i = 0
for c in string:    
    convertedString += c + ''.join(vowelsAndNumbers[i:i+1])
    i+=1

# if remaining vowels, add to convertedString
convertedString += ''.join(vowelsAndNumbers[i:])

print convertedString
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import chain, zip_longest

char_list = 'asftiopeiopv'
vowels_and_numbers = 'aeiou0123456789'
vowels, consts = [], []

for c in char_list:
    if c in vowels_and_numbers:
        vowels.append(c)
    else:
        consts.append(c)

print(''.join([c for c in chain(*zip_longest(consts, vowels)) if c]))
```

Answer (score 0):

- partition the input into two lists, e.g. `con` and `vow`
- sort each list randomly (use `random.shuffle`)
- join the two lists (`[con[0], vow[0], con[1], ...]`)